# Codificacion archivo posgresql

Tags: postgresql, codificación

Estoy intentando cargar datos a una tabla en PosgreSQL, estos datos contienen cadenas con caracteres especiales ademas de que el archivo contiene mil millones de registros, por lo que al momento de subir la data me sale un error; en especifico al leer los datos con la letra ñ.
Ya intente cambiar la codificación a UTF-8 desde power shell pero me sigue mostrando el error.
¿Alguna idea de como puedo codificar mi archivo ya que pareciere que no está codificando todos los datos o desde donde puedo subirlo?.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado, las preguntas que requieren opiniones se pueden realizar en [chat] (tienes que obtener reputación), te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Es un archivo de texto el que se carga?

Comment: en efecto es un archivo de texto (txt)

Comment: Intenta esto: Ábrelo con el bloc de notas y pones guardar como y ahí cambias la codificación https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9XQB.png

Comment: ya intente abrirlo en un bloc de notas, el tema esta en que el archivo tiene millones de registros y no el bloc de notas no lo abre.

Comment: tambien intente partirlo en pedazos de manera que lo pudiera leer bloc de notas para cambiarle la codificacion, despues los uni nuevamente pero tampoco funcionó.